# I am running my telegram bot code locally and there are no errors. But I can't get my telegram bot to start

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I am a beginner in python programming and I got the idea to write a telegram chat summarization bot in python. I used python-telegram-bot(v20.5) module and wrote the code mostly with the help of ChatGPT and other AIs. I am trying to run the bot locally. When I run the script, I got no errors or nothing. But when I try to start the bot in telegram, nothing happens. Below is my code, please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, ConversationHandler, Application
import requests
import datetime
from queue import Queue
import asyncio

# Bot Token
bot = telegram.Bot(token='Correctly pasted my bot token here')
# Create an updater object that will receive updates from Telegram
update_queue = Queue()
updater = Updater(bot=bot, update_queue=update_queue)
# Create an Application object with bot token
application = Application.builder().token('Correctly pasted my bot token here').build()

# Define some constants for the conversation states
CHAT, DATE = range(2)

# Define a function that takes a chat id, a start date and an end date as parameters and returns a summary of the chat messages in that period using the meaningcloud summarization API
def get_summary(chat_id, start_date, end_date):
    # Initialize an empty list to store the chat messages
    messages = []
    # Get the chat history from the bot object using the get_chat_history method
    # This method returns a tuple of (messages, next_offset)
    # We need to loop until we get all the messages or reach the end date
    offset = 0 # The offset is the ID of the first message to be returned
    while True:
        # Get a batch of 100 messages from the chat history
        history = bot.get_chat_history(chat_id, offset=offset)
        # Loop through each message in the history
        for message in history[0]:
            # Get the message date as a datetime object
            message_date = message.date
            # Check if the message date is within the date range
            if start_date <= message_date <= end_date:
                # Check if the message has text content
                if message.text:
                    # Append the message text to the messages list
                    messages.append(message.text)
            # If the message date is before the start date, we can break the loop as we have reached the end of the date range
            elif message_date < start_date:
                break
        # If there are no more messages to fetch, we can break the loop as we have reached the end of the chat history
        if not history[1]:
            break
        # Otherwise, we update the offset with the next offset value returned by the get_chat_history method
        else:
            offset = history[1]
    # Join all the messages into a single string with newline characters as separators
    text = '\n'.join(messages)
    # Check if the text is not empty
    if text:
        # Make a request to the meaningcloud summarization API using the requests module
        # We need to pass our API key, the text to summarize and the number of sentences in the summary as parameters
        response = requests.post('https://api.meaningcloud.com/summarization-1.0', data={'key': 'Correctly pasted my meaningcloud API key here', 'txt': text, 'sentences': 5})
        # Check if the request was successful by looking at the status code
        if response.status_code == 200:
            # Parse the response as a JSON object and get the summary field
            summary = response.json()['summary']
            # Return the summary as a string
            return summary
        # If the request failed, we return an error message with the status code
        else:
            return f'Sorry, something went wrong with the meaningcloud summarization API. The status code was {response.status_code}.'
    # If the text is empty, we return a message saying that there were no messages in that date range
    else:
        return 'Sorry, there were no messages in that date range.'


# Define a function that takes an update and a context as parameters and asks the user to choose a chat to summarize from their chat list
def choose_chat(update, context):
    # Get all chats that are currently opened by using bot.get_chats() method.
    chats = bot.get_chats()
    # Initialize an empty list to store chat titles.
    chat_titles = []
    for chat in chats:
      chat_titles.append(chat.title)
    
    update.message.reply_text(f'Please choose one of these chats: {chat_titles}')
    
    return CHAT

# Define a function that takes an update and a context as parameters and asks user to enter a date range to summarize.
def enter_date(update, context):
  user_input = update.message.text
  
  if user_input not in chat_titles:
      update.message.reply_text(f'Sorry, {user_input} is not a valid chat. Please choose one of these chats: {chat_titles}')
      return CHAT
  else:
      # Get the chat id from the user input by using bot.get_chat() method.
      chat = bot.get_chat(user_input)
      chat_id = chat.id
      # Store the chat id in the user data dictionary for later use.
      context.user_data['chat_id'] = chat_id
      # Ask the user to enter a date range in the format YYYY-MM-DD - YYYY-MM-DD.
      update.message.reply_text('Please enter a date range in the format YYYY-MM-DD - YYYY-MM-DD.')
      return DATE

# Define a function that takes an update and a context as parameters and validates the date range input and calls the get_summary function to get the summary of the chat messages in that period.
def summarize(update, context):
    # Get the date range input from the user
    date_range = update.message.text
    # Try to split the date range by the dash character and parse each part as a date object using the datetime module
    try:
        start_date_str, end_date_str = date_range.split('-')
        start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date_str.strip(), '%Y-%m-%d')
        end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date_str.strip(), '%Y-%m-%d')
        # Check if the start date is before or equal to the end date
        if start_date <= end_date:
            # Store the start date and end date in the user data dictionary for later use
            context.user_data['start_date'] = start_date
            context.user_data['end_date'] = end_date
            # Call the get_summary function to get the summary of the chat messages in that period
            summary = get_summary(context.user_data['chat_id'], start_date, end_date)
            # Send the summary to the user
            update.message.reply_text(summary)
            # End the conversation
            return ConversationHandler.END
        # If the start date is after the end date, we send an error message and ask the user to enter a valid date range again
        else:
            update.message.reply_text('Sorry, the start date must be before or equal to the end date. Please enter a valid date range.')
            return DATE
    # If there is an exception while parsing the dates, we send an error message and ask the user to enter a valid date range again
    except Exception as e:
        update.message.reply_text(f'Sorry, something went wrong while parsing your dates. Please enter a valid date range. The error was: {e}')
        return DATE

# Define a function that takes an update and a context as parameters and cancels or restarts the conversation
def cancel(update, context):
    # Get the user input
    user_input = update.message.text.lower()
    # Check if the user input is 'cancel' or 'restart'
    if user_input == 'cancel':
        # Send a message saying that the conversation is cancelled
        update.message.reply_text('OK, I have cancelled this conversation.')
        # End the conversation
        return ConversationHandler.END
    elif user_input == 'restart':
        # Send a message saying that the conversation is restarted
        update.message.reply_text('OK, I have restarted this conversation.')
        # Go back to the first state of choosing a chat
        return choose_chat(update, context)
    else:
        # Send a message saying that the user input is not valid and provide options to cancel or restart
        update.message.reply_text('Sorry, I did not understand your input. You can type "cancel" to cancel this conversation or "restart" to restart it.')
        return ConversationHandler.END

# Create a conversation handler for the summarization bot
conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[CommandHandler('summarize', choose_chat)],
    states={
        CHAT: [MessageHandler(filters.Text, enter_date)],
        DATE: [MessageHandler(filters.Text, summarize)]
    },
    fallbacks=[MessageHandler(filters.Text, cancel)]
)
# Add the handler to the application
application.add_handler(conv_handler)

# Start the application
application.run_polling()
```

Tried to run the telegram bot code locally but can't get the bot to start.

Comment: I strongly recommend not to rely on chatGPT too much with PTB code. We have seen many users run into pitfalls because it is mostly trained on older versions of the library. In your code snippet, there is not a single `async` or `await`, which are needed for v20.x. I also highly doubt that this code is *not* throwing exceptions on your local machine. You probably just don't see them because you didn't [configure logging](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Exceptions%2C-Warnings-and-Logging)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use examples from PTB documentation, and I doubt that Telegram made chat history available from TelegramBotAPI, try to log messages into the database, for the beginning you can try sqlite3, but in production mode I recemmend to use anything else like MySQL or Postgresql.

There is also messed up with variables scope, try to learn something about it especially in python (about `local` `nonlocal` and `global` scopes)